# Why can't mono C# find System.IO.File with my code?

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to deserialize a very large json file (63mb) by parsing it directly using JSON.Net and StreamReader. I am developing in Ubuntu 18.04 using mono+monodevelop. I need to keep things as portable as I can.

on [this page](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) of JSON.Net's documentation it gives an example of how to directly read in a file to deserialize

```
// deserialize JSON directly from a file
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\movie.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    Movie movie2 = (Movie)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Movie));
}
```

So I'm trying to do this

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private void LoadJson(string path)
{
    using (StreamReader json_file = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        blah blah
    }
}
```

however, monodevelop complains with `The name 'File' does not exist in the current context`

I can't even address it directly with `System.IO.File.OpenText`

Does anybody know why mono isn't finding System.IO.File?

Comment: Does `c:\movie.json` exist on Ubuntu? The C drive is specific to the Windows OS.

Comment: Just to make sure: Have you double-checked the line number of the error? Does the error line number actually match the code line that you suspect is the culprit (`... = File.OpenText( ... ))`)?

Comment: @Helios as it says there is no c;\ in ubunto

Comment: As shown in my example code, I am not copying it line for line. The path is created elsewhere using portable functions Path.GetDirectoryName() and Path.Combine()

The line number matches and the error is exactly as I stated at the end of my post. Anyways I found the answer, as posted below

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason.

Apparently the full .NET API is not available if I create a portable library project. Which kind of bites because I need this code to run on at least MacOS and Windows, but I'll figure something out.

Comment: as [docs says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.opentext?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to) `File.OpenText()` is in .net Standard from version 1.3. as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) mono 4.6 is .net Standard 1.3 compatible, so just update your mono.